# how to add if statement to groovy

Tags: grails, gsp

Ok I'm completely new to grails and groovy and I have a button that I want to add some statements to. I have a similar setup in coldfusion that I want to port over to be the same in the below groovy code.
I'll show you the CF code first and then the groovy code that it needs to work in.

```
<li id="menuBtn"><CFIF application.sf.secure.auth_feature('DTD')><a id="dtdItem" class="dtd <CFIF url.activity EQ "DTD">selected</CFIF>" href=<CFOUTPUT>"#application.http_path#services.cfm?activity=DTD"</CFOUTPUT>><b>DTD</b></a><CFELSE><a id="dtdItem" class="dtd" href="javascript:;" onclick="ERRORS.show('bla bla bla');return false;"><b>DTD</b></a></CFIF></li>
```

So I guess in a nutshell I'm trying to write the if and else part of the above into my li tag but using groovy syntax.

I'm told in the grails application I'm working the path to the auth_feature like in the coldfusion can be got like this.

```
${auth_feature(name:'DTD')}
```

So here is the code that I have now that I need to add the if and else statement with the javascript error.

```
<li><a class="<g:if test="${controllerName == 'DTD'}">selected</g:if>" href="<%= grailsApplication.config.http_path %>DTD"><strong>DTD</strong></a></li>
```

Again I'm sure this is super easy for a grails or groovy developer but I'm totally new to language and am hoping to learn from this.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not clear on what the issue is; there's an `<g:if>` tag, which you already know about, a `<g:else>` tag, which is analogous to the CF tags you already know about--what specifically is the question?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<li><a class="${controllerName == 'DTD' ? 'selected' : ''}" href="${grailsApplication.config.http_path}DTD"><strong>DTD</strong></a></li>
```